# Get some values in json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a json that looks like this.
How can I retrieve the information inside the group "demo", without looking into the array like: `json['data'][0]` I wanted to retrieve the info reading the first value.. "group" and if it matches demo, get all that group info.

```
 {
      "filter": "*",
      "data": [
        {
          "group": "asdasd",
          "enable": 1,
          "timeout": 7,
          "otpMode": 0,
          "company": "cool",
          "signature": "ou yeah",
          "supportPage": "",
          "newsLanguages": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "newsLanguagesTotal": 0
        },
        {
          "group": "demo",
          "enable": 1,
          "timeout": 7,
          "otpMode": 0,
          "company": "pppppooo",
          "signature": "TTCM",
          "supportPage": "http://www.trz<xa",
          "newsLanguages": [
            0,
            0
          ],
          "newsLanguagesTotal": 0
        }
      ]
    }
```

So long I have:

```
   let json = JSON.parse(body);
    //console.log(json);
    console.log(json['data'][1]);
```

Which access to "demo"

Comment: Are you asking how you would find all the objects in the data array where the 'group' property is "demo"?

Comment: yes, but looking for that value in a loop ... not directly like json['data'][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process each "data item" and check for the group value. If it matches, then do something.

```
var json = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

for(var i=0;i<json.data.length;i++){
    if(json.data[i].group == "demo"){
        var group = json.data[i];
        // Process the group info
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the filter()

```
json.data.filter(function(item){
    return item.group === "demo";
});
```

this will return the objects that have "demo" in the group property

Or if you want to get fancy es6 with it

```
json.data.filter(item => item.group === "demo");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the key "group" is missing for any of the records, a simple check (similar to the code provided by @MarkSkayff) will give an error. To fix this, check to see if json["data"][i] exists *and* check if json["data"[i]["group"] also exists

```
function json_data(){

  var res=[]
  for (var i in json["data"]){ 
  if(json["data"][i] && json["data"][i]["group"] === "demo"){ //strict comparison and boolean shortcircuiting
   res.push(json["data"][i]) 
  }    
 }
 console.log(res)
}
```

The result is stored in res

Not enough space here but for more on boolean short circuiting read [this explanation of dealing with irregular JSON data](https://medium.com/the-n00b-code-chronicles/a-n00ber-pattern-for-taming-the-wild-data-web-da10e81a035c#.uw75n4c0w)